# Recursive type constrain on object property values

Tags: typescript, recursion, indexing

I am trying to constrain the property types on an Object in a recursive way. The end goal is that the given object's properties needs to be `number`, `string`, or another nested object which fits the same description (properties are of type `number`, `string` or further nested)

Currently the only way I found is to use index signature. Like demonstrated in this [code example in this TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20AllowedTypes%20%3D%20string%20%7C%20number%20%7C%20ConstrainedClass%3B%0D%0Atype%20ConstrainedClass%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20AllowedTypes%20%7D%3B%0D%0Aclass%20Test2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20AllowedTypes%3B%20%2F%2F%20this%20line%20is%20needed%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20prop1%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Test1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20AllowedTypes%3B%20%2F%2F%20this%20line%20is%20needed%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20prop1%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20prop2%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20nestedProp%3A%20Test2%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20somefunction%3CT%20extends%20ConstrainedClass%3E(param%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Asomefunction(new%20Test1())%3B), however it is not perfect as extra lines needs to be put into the class, as well as problems it leads to in other places in my code base (it prevent type inference to work properly in certain places)

```
type AllowedTypes = string | number | ConstrainedClass;
type ConstrainedClass = { [key: string]: AllowedTypes };
class Test2 {
    [key: string]: AllowedTypes; // this line is needed
    public prop1: number;
}
class Test1 {
    [key: string]: AllowedTypes; // this line is needed
    public prop1: string;
    public prop2: number;
    public nestedProp: Test2;
}

function somefunction<T extends ConstrainedClass>(param: T) {
    return;
}

somefunction(new Test1());
```

I wonder if there's a better way to do this?

Comment: You can't constrain types using an index type, so you can still have `class Test3 { [key: string]: AllowedTypes, someOtherProp: SomeOtherType }` and be valid. You want to restrict all property types to number or string or a recursive object with properties of only number or string?

Comment: @ExplosionPills indeed, I would like to achieve the recursive constrain as you described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get what you want, using mapped [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) and self-bounded generics (which I can't find any good TypeScript documentation about; but there are [analogous uses in Java](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=136394) which might be good reads?).  Let's see:

```
type Constrained<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? Constrained<T[K]> : 
    T[K] extends string | number ? T[K] : never
}
```

A `Constrained<T>` takes a type `T` and recursively goes down through it, checking that each property is either a `string`, a `number`, or an `object` that also conforms to `Constrained`.  Any property it doesn't like is replaced with `never`.

With that you can create your interfaces like this:

```
interface Test extends Constrained<Test> {
    a: string; // okay
    b: number; // okay
    // c: boolean; // uncommenting this causes an error 
    d: { foo: string;  bar: string } // okay
}
```

Notice the self-bounded generic, where `Test` is declared to extend `Constrained<Test>`.  This enforces the exact constraint you want without index signatures.  If you add a property that doesn't meet the constraint, it will give you an error, usually something like `Type 'XXX' is not assignable to type 'never'`.

To do it with classes would look something like this:

```
class Test2 implements Constrained<Test2> {
  public prop1: number = 1;
}
class Test1 implements Constrained<Test1> {
  public prop1: string = "a";
  public prop2: number = 1;
  public nestedProp: Test2 = new Test2();
}
```

(I added initializers since TypeScript complains now when you don't initialize class instances).  And your function works like this:

```
function someFunction<T extends Constrained<T>>(x: T) { }
someFunction(new Test1());
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!